# How to fix ' ERROR in node_modules/@types/prismjs/index.d.ts error Cannot find name Required' error in angular

Tags: angular, tsconfig, prismjs

I install `@types/prismjs` but i have this problem 
in `node_modules/@types/prismjs/index.d.ts(316,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Required'`.

Angular

config.ts

```
    { "compileOnSave": false, "compilerOptions":
 { "baseUrl": "./", "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc", "sourceMap": true,
 "declaration": false, "module": "es2015", "moduleResolution": "node",
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, "experimentalDecorators": true, "target": "es5", "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ], "lib": [ "es2017", "dom" ] } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `"es2015.symbol"` to lib in `tsconfig.json.` Or use es2015.

Comment: i try it but ftill found an error 
This is my config.ts
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
   
    }
  }
}

Comment: { "compileOnSave": false, "compilerOptions": { "baseUrl": "./", "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc", "sourceMap": true, "declaration": false, "module": "es2015", "moduleResolution": "node", "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, "experimentalDecorators": true, "target": "es5", "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ], "lib": [ "es2015.symbol",] } } }

Comment: try removing dom in lib